# Как корректно рассчитать дату три месяца назад?

Tags: php, дата

Дано: дата 31 декабря 2004 года. Задача: определить дату, которая была три месяца назад. В MySQL считаем так:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2004-12-31', INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Получаем 2004-09-30. Эта дата нас устраивает и мы хотим ее получить на уровне PHP:

```
$maxDate = '2004-12-31';
$timestamp = ;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($maxDate . ' - 3 month'));
```

Получаем 2004-10-01. Логично, но не совсем то, что ожидаем.

Пробуем по-другому:

```
$Date = new DateTime('2004-12-31');
$Date->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('3 months'));
echo $Date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Опять же получаем 1 октября.

Как, не городя огород, в PHP получить ожидаемую дату?

Comment: Писать свою функцию нужно. У авторов php и mysql в каждом месяце года по 30.4375 дню ;)

Comment: Проще определить для себя сколько в месяце дней (например 30) и исходить из этого.. Либо писать свою функцию

Comment: Самое интересное то, что PostgreSQL тоже возвращает "2004-06-30"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский проще? Да это самый сложный вариант

Comment: То есть, вы хотите, если в целевом месяце дней меньше, чем текущая дата, брать последний день того месяца. Это всего лишь один if

Comment: @ilyaplot с чего бы это самый сложный вариант? 90 дней (или кратные 30 - в зависимости от количества вычитаемых месяцев) вычесть сложнее, чем написать логику вычитания месяцев? серьезно?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я не знал о баге. В итоге и написал вариант, который отнимает количество дней в месяце :)

Comment: @ilyaplot `Я не знал о баге` - ну тогда прощаю))) вообще это не баг и есть во многих языках и надо поэтому знать нюанс и быть осторожным. А поведение вполне логично. Например почему с 20 октября до 20 ноября месяц - это 31 день, а с 20 февраля по 20 марта - 28? Отсюда и вычитание целого числа месяцев ведет себя вполне логично ибо "а куда считать при...?"..для меня вот лично не логично что  29/30/31 марта минус месяц - это всё 28 февраля.....В общем, кмк, для вычитания месяцев нужно для начала определить - что именно является месяцем и каков константный результат ожидается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Date = new DateTime('2004-12-31');
$shift = -3;

//  сохраним день
$day = $Date->format('d');
// первый день целевого месяца  
$Date->modify('first day of this month')->modify(($shift > 0 ? '+':'') . $shift . ' months');
// если наш день больше числа дней в месяце, возьмем последний
$day = $day > $Date->format('t') ? $Date->format('t') : $day;
// готово
echo $Date->modify('+' . $day-1 . ' days')->format('c');
```

Comment: как по мне, так сомнительно, что 29/30/31 мая минус 3 месяца это всё 28 февраля

Comment: Для 2005-01-01 получим 2004-10-31, для 2004-12-31 тоже получим 2004-10-31. Думаю, мой метод более корректный. Отнимал 3 месяца

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Это  к логике вопроса. Например, посчитать дни выплаты кредита - тоже не переносят на другой месяц

Comment: @ilyaplot а запустить код не пробовали? https://eval.in/919640

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, в PHP есть бага. http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php#119082

```
function subMonths(\Datetime $dateTime, int $months)
{
    if ($invert = $months < 0) {
        $months *= -1;
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<$months; $i++) {
        $daysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dateTime->format('m'), $dateTime->format('Y'));
        $dateTime->modify(($invert ? '-' : '+') . $daysOfMonth . ' day');
    }
    return $dateTime;
}

$dateTime = new \DateTime('2004-12-31');
echo subMonths($dateTime, -3)->format('Y-m-d'); // 2004-09-30
```

Comment: Не-не-не. Тут вы просто вычли несколько часов из даты (или прибавили - в зависимости от часового пояса). Если попробовать считать от 2004-12-30, то получится 2004-09-29.

Comment: Если от 2004-12-31 получаем 2004-09-30, то логично получить для 2004-12-30 дату  2004-09-29

Comment: Логично, но не то.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin А вообще, в комментариях на официальном сайте упоминалась проблема http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php#119082

Comment: Да, я видел тот комментарий. Проблема понятна, не понятно, как решить ее малой кровью.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Такое решение устроит?

```
echo findDate('2004-12-31', -3); // 2004-09-29

function findDate($start_date, $months) {
    $start_date_object = new DateTime($start_date);
    $date_interval = findInterval($months, $start_date_object);
    $end_date_object = $start_date_object->add($date_interval);
    $end_date_object->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    return $end_date_object->format('Y-m-d');
}

function findInterval($n_months, DateTime $start_date_object) {
    $date_of_last_day_next_month = new DateTime($start_date_object->format('Y-m-d'));
    $date_of_last_day_next_month->modify('last day of +'.$n_months.' month');
    if($start_date_object->format('d') > $date_of_last_day_next_month->format('d')) {
        return $start_date_object->diff($date_of_last_day_next_month);
    } else {
        return new DateInterval('P'.$n_months.'M');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ожидаем то 2004-09-30